# Update constraints programmatically?

Tags: ios

I have a group of views in my view controller, each set with a constraint of 15 from the previous.  When I press a button elsewhere on the VC, I have one of the views, near the top, double in height. How do I get the rest of the views to snap to their new constraints?

Comment: You need to provide information about what constraints you have, and how you want the views to move when your one view doubles in height.

Comment: I have a group of UIViews  each with a constraint of being 25 underneath the previous one.  When one of them resizes to twice it's original height, I want all the views underneath it to move down to satisfy the constraint of being 25 underneath it.  Right now, when I change the frame of the view, the view resizes but everything else does not update.

Comment: If the one that doubles in height has a constraint to the one under it, and that one has a constraint to the one under it, etc., then they should all move down when the height changes. You shouldn't be changing the frame of the view, as you said, you should be modifying it's height constraint.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLayoutConstraint *sample = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:yourTargetView
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                           toItem:yourTargetsParentView
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                       multiplier:0.00
                                                                         constant:100];
[yourTargetsParentView addConstraint:sample];
```